# How to call Javascript function from Html.DropDownList in ASP.Net?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to call a javascript function from a Html.DropDownlist helper during the on change function.

The function works with a hard coded list.For example

```
        <select id="leave" onchange="leaveChange(this)">
            <option value="5">Get Married</option>
            <option value="100">Have a Baby</option>
            <option value="90">Adopt a Child</option>
            <option value="15">Retire</option>
            <option value="15">Military Leave</option>
            <option value="15">Medical Leave</option>
        </select>
```

My javascript function is

```
@section Scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function leaveChange(control) {
               alert("I am an alert box!");

            }             


        </script>
    }
```

When I change an element in the dropdown list I get the pop up alert.

However, when I do this using the Html dropdown helper, I'm unable to see it.

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserID", null, new { @onchange = "javascript:leavechange(this)" })
```

How do I call a javascript method using the @Html.DropdownList

Comment: Can you check source code of your generated HTML? As it look like a typo in your @HTML.DropDownList helper in name of leaveChange function.

Comment: Oh my Word!!!!! I can't believe I wasted half a day because of a case mismatch in the function call!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a mvc dropddownlist with mvc helpers like this as per your requirement:-

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, new List<SelectListItem>{new SelectListItem() {Text = "Get Married", Value="5"},new SelectListItem() {Text = "Have a Baby", Value="100"},new SelectListItem() {Text = "Adopt a Child", Value="90"},}, "Select Type", new { @class = "form-control", id="leave"})
   ```
2. and in scripts, you can control with onchange action od that dropdownlist

   ```
   $("#leave").on("change",function(){
   alert("I am an alert box! "+"and my value is: "+$(this).val());
   //do your stuff here
   });
   ```